# Having problems with React Router Auth redirection

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use react router auth redirects as it shows here (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow), but I am running into so many problems. I am currently getting an error: cannot read property 'state' of undefined. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I would love to hear any notes/improvements that you have on my code (this is my time using React).

The error is coming from the {from} in the Login class render function 
Here is a link to the codesandbox, it has the more complete code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-mendel-hgvun

```
`const auth = {
isAuthenticated: false,
authenticate(callback) {
  this.isAuthenticated = true;
  setTimeout(callback, 30000);
},
signout(callback) {
  this.isAuthenticated = false;
  setTimeout(callback, 30000);
}
};

 //Class Login:
 handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var payload = {
    "email": this.state.email,
    "password": this.state.password
  }
  axios.post({url}"/login", payload)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.data.status == "success") {
      auth.authenticate(() => {
        this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true});
      });
      this.setState({authenticated: true});
      this.setState({token: res.data.data.token})
    }
}


render() {
  let {from} = this.props.location.state || {from: {pathname: '/'}};
  const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
  if (redirectToReferrer == true) {
    return <Redirect to={from} />
  }
  return (
          <form>
            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          </form>
  );
}
  }

 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
  authed === true
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }} />
)} />
  );

//called in class App like this 
render() {
const {authenticated}=this.state;
return(
  <React.Fragment className='root'>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login callbackToParent={this.loginCallback} /> }exact/>
          <Route path="/register" render={() => <Register callbackFromParent={this.registerCallback} /> } exact/>
  <PrivateRoute authed={authenticated} path="/" render={() => <Home tokenFromParent={this.state.token} /> } exact/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>

  );`
```

Comment: Is handleSubmit function works?? I don't feel like URL is not right there??

Comment: where does function expression PrivateRoute declared at? (which file)

Comment: Have you configured your router properly? State is undefined probably because the component does not receive the prop 'state' from react router. Could you share  complete code from https://codesandbox.io/ or https://jsbin.com/

Comment: Here is the link to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-mendel-hgvun

Answer (score 0):

I think the function expression PrivateRoute is invoked right after this.props.location.state is used. If you are using a function expression you must declare it before using it.

Maybe you can try declaring the function expression before render method

```
 //Class Login:
 handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var payload = {
    "email": this.state.email,
    "password": this.state.password
  }
  axios.post({url}"/login", payload)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.data.status == "success") {
      auth.authenticate(() => {
        this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true});
      });
      this.setState({authenticated: true});
      this.setState({token: res.data.data.token})
    }
}

// declare function expression here so that the interpreter reaches the code first before its being used
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
  authed === true
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }} />
)} />
);


render() {
  let {from} = this.props.location.state || {from: {pathname: '/'}};
  const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
  if (redirectToReferrer == true) {
    return <Redirect to={from} />
  }
  return (
          <form>
            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          </form>
  );
}
  }
```

or changing the function expression to a regular function might work!